# Flush footer to the bottom of the page in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4

I have my template structure like this

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="content">
    <nav id="content-header">
    ...code here...
    </nav>
    <main id="content-main">
    ...code here...
    </main>
    <div id="footer">
    ...code here...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However the footer does not flush to the bottom as expected. (I'm not looking for a sticky footer). How to send the footer down with the code im using.

Few weeks ago i read an articles that we need to use id="content" and content-header content-footer accordingly for bootstrap in order to make this work. I've lost the article link, hence posting a question here.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have the footer ALWAYS at the bottom of the page/viewport. If so, I can help. Could you explain where the footer should be placed in these two scenarios 1. when there are more content than the viewport height. 2- when there is not enough content?

Comment: For example, my login page does not have much content so the footer does not stay at the bottom. I want it to stay at the bottom on these pages when there is less content on the page. Scenario 2 would suit better

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bootstrap has neither any  `id` selector nor `.content-header` or `.content-footer`.

---

There are a couple of ways that you can achieve it. I want to show you 3 of them.

### Flex - flex-grow-1

1. Use the `h-100` class for all the parents of the `#content` div including `html` and `body`.
2. Use `d-flex`,  `flex-column`, and `h-100` classes for the `#content` div.
3. Use `flex-grow-1` on the `main` content.

*You should use boostrap version 4.1  or higher because the lower version does not have `flex-grow-1`*.

See this pen. I recommend you to add and remove texts so that you see  that it works.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKEjLR

### Flex - mt-auto

1. Use the `h-100` class for all the parents of the `#content` div including `html` and `body`.
2. Use `d-flex`,  `flex-column`, and `h-100` classes for the `#content` div.
3. Use `mt-auto` for the `footer`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app" class="h-100">
  <div id="content" class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <nav id="content-header" class="bg-info p-5">
    ...code here...
    </nav>
    <main id="content-main" class="bg-primary p-5">
    ...code here...
      
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat hic aspernatur quibusdam alias delectus odit officiis in, est sapiente deserunt harum aliquam at mollitia deleniti labore corrupti illum recusandae dolorum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste inventore voluptatum sint mollitia unde quisquam numquam vitae? Id, quia. Cupiditate nam vero natus, facere nesciunt vel delectus assumenda eos sequi!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non asperiores perferendis quae harum ab, dolorem dicta repudiandae quisquam repellendus eveniet, totam voluptatum, eum cum nobis? Atque alias dolores nam illum.
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi odit aspernatur minima tempora! Similique consequatur distinctio odit nemo, pariatur consectetur ad ipsum provident corporis nostrum culpa cumque doloremque quo quia.
    </main>
    <div id="footer" class="bg-danger p-5 mt-auto">
    ...code here...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### min-height: calc(100vh - (header + footer height));

We have used this one, because some very old browsers does not support `flex` box. Check browser support for [flex](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

1. Find the sum of height of footer and header, suppose it is `120px`
2. Set `min-height` of  `main` to `calc(100vh - 120px)`;

```css
main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
}
```

See this pen.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKExLm

Visit these pages to learn the other methods

https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx