# How to position (flush down) my footer with large screen size, when using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have problem with my footer. I am using ASP.NET Core 2 MVC, with Razor View.
Right now I tryed everything from this, including comments:
https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/ & https://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Note, that I do not want fixed footer. I know that there is several similar topics in SO, but I tryed already everything I found. I belive that I am missig something obvoius. I work on this whole day already and it just stops me.

Every time my footer is rendered just below `Edit`, `Delete` buttons, or somewhere in the middle of page. I am guessing that it might be something with my `_Layout` architecutre or for in `Index` file is causing ot somehow.

My `_Layout.cshtml` looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <!--HEADER-->
        </div>
        <div class="content">
    <!--BODY-->
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
    <!--FOOTER-->
            <footer>
                <div></div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My `Index.cshtml` looks like (for most of the cases footer was rendered below `Edit`/`Delete` form:

```
<div>
    @if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary adminBtn">Add new project</a>
    }
    <div>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="projectContainer col-lg-6">
                @if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <form asp-action="Delete" method="post">
                        <a asp-action="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"
                           asp-route-projectID="@item.ProjectID">
                            Edit
                        </a>
                        <input type="hidden" name="ProjectID" value="@item.ProjectID" />

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </form>

                }
                <div class="innerContainer" style="background-color: @item.BackColor">
                    <div class="projectHeader col-xs-12">
                        @item.Name
                    </div>

                    <div class="hyperButton col-xs-12">
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-projectID="@item.ProjectID">See more ></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="projectPictures col-xs-12">
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-projectID="@item.ProjectID"><img src="@item.PictureUrl" asp-append-version="true" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

My `site.css` looks like that right now:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(/src/img/footBG.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-top: 3px solid #557DA8;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footText {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

UPDATE with source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="/src/lib/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/src/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/site.css" />
    <style>
        .input-validation-error {
            border-color: red;
            background-color: #fee;
        }
    </style>
    <title>
        Przemyslaw Bak - My projects
    </title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <!--HEADER-->
            <div class="mainHeader">
                <div class="helloTextContainer col-12">
                    <div class="helloTxtWrapper">Hi! I am</div>
                </div>
                <div class="mainTextContainer col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="mainTxtWrapper">Przemyslaw Bak {developer}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="socialContainer col-sm-3 hidden-sm-down">
                    <!--VIEW COMPONENT-->

<a href="fb link" target="_blank" class="socialIcon"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
<a href="li link" target="_blank" class="socialIcon"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
<a href="gh link" target="_blank" class="socialIcon"><i class="fab fa-github-square"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mainNavbar">
                <div><a class="mainButton projects" href="/">my projects</a></div>
                <div><a class="mainButton technologies" href="/MyTechnologies">technologies</a></div>
                <div><a class="mainButton about" href="/Literature">literature</a></div>
                <div><a class="mainButton contact" href="/ContactMe">about and contact</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="stickyNavbar">
                <div><a class="mainButton projects" href="/">my projects</a></div>
                <div><a class="mainButton technologies" href="/MyTechnologies">technologies</a></div>
                <div><a class="mainButton about" href="/Literature">literature</a></div>
                <div><a class="mainButton contact" href="/ContactMe">about and contact</a></div>
            </div>
            <!--HERE TRIGGERS APP.JS-->
            <div class="emptySpace" id="app"></div>
        </div>

        <!--BODY-->
        <div class="content">

<!--button-->
<style>
    .projects {
        color: gray !important;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div>
            <div class="projectContainer col-lg-6">
                <div class="innerContainer" style="background-color: #E8E8E8">
                    <div class="projectHeader col-xs-12">
                        Name of the project
                    </div>

                    <div class="hyperButton col-xs-12">
                        <a href="/MyProjects/Details?projectID=3">See more ></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="projectPictures col-xs-12">
                        <a href="/MyProjects/Details?projectID=3"><img src="#" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="projectContainer col-lg-6">
                <div class="innerContainer" style="background-color: #fafafa">
                    <div class="projectHeader col-xs-12">
                        Name of the project
                    </div>

                    <div class="hyperButton col-xs-12">
                        <a href="/MyProjects/Details?projectID=2">See more ></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="projectPictures col-xs-12">
                        <a href="/MyProjects/Details?projectID=2"><img src="/src/img/website1.png?v=pdiYJ15drelz9-8uTNfrtUab7HjRkk9REgc4EOUOLHU" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="projectContainer col-lg-6">
                <div class="innerContainer" style="background-color: #f9fbf8">
                    <div class="projectHeader col-xs-12">
                        Best project ever
                    </div>

                    <div class="hyperButton col-xs-12">
                        <a href="/MyProjects/Details?projectID=1">See more ></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="projectPictures col-xs-12">
                        <a href="/MyProjects/Details?projectID=1"><img src="/src/img/website1.png?v=pdiYJ15drelz9-8uTNfrtUab7HjRkk9REgc4EOUOLHU" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

        </div>

        <!--FOOTER-->
        <div class="footer">
            <footer>
                <div class="footText">&copy 2018 - Przemyslaw Bak</div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently after scrolling down my footer looks like this (2018 - Przemyslaw Bak):
[image]

UPDATE2:
I am using Bootstrap 4, maybe it changes something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using bootstrap 4 there good solition for you, 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-self 
you need self item end if you wanna use to bootstrap I think you should be use this.

Comment: Thanks, at the final I found solution with Bootstrap 4.1 and 'flex'

Answer (score 1):

Take out that position: absolute; in the footer CSS

```
.footer {
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(/src/img/footBG.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
border-top: 3px solid #557DA8;
height: 75px;
text-align: center;
```

}

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.footer {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(/src/img/footBG.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-top: 3px solid #557DA8;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footText {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <!--HEADER-->
        </div>
        <div class="content">
    <!--BODY-->
            <p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p><p>@RenderBody()</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
    <!--FOOTER-->
            <footer>
                <div>Div inside footer</div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I do not know why, but it renders me the footer now just a pixel over `Edit` and `Delete`

Comment: Can you paste the HTML from your browser via View Source?

Comment: @Przemyslaw.Pszemek That's not the HTML you posted an image of, at least I dont see any buttons: https://jsfiddle.net/bnh8gqcz/6/

Comment: Buttons are displayed only if admin is logged in. It is the only difference.

Comment: It's not easy to debug something if you post an image of one thing and then the source code from another thing. Does the problem display in the jsfiddle for you? https://jsfiddle.net/bnh8gqcz/6/

Comment: Sorry for that. I fout it will not change anything. Anyway, after your comments I decided to investigate closer html, not css, and my conclusion was that Bootstrap is messing up something. Finally I found solution with Bootstrap 4.1. Thanks anyway for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

After Viktor`s comments I stripped out my HTML code and started to suspect, that my Bootstrap (previously 4.0.6) is messing up something.

So I started to Google "flush footer bootstrap" and I found this:
[Flush footer to the bottom of the page in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674837/flush-footer-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-bootstrap-4)

After installation Bootstrap 4.1.X files, I changed my site.css and _Layout.cshtml as follows:

```
body, wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(/src/img/footBG.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-top: 3px solid #557DA8;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footText {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<body>
    <wrapper class="d-flex flex-column">
        //nav bar

        //render body
        <main class="container-fluid py-3 flex-fill">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
        //footer
        <footer>
            <div class="footText">&copy @DateTime.Now.Year - Przemyslaw Bak</div>
        </footer>
    </wrapper>
//scripts
</body>
```

And it works!