# CSS Flexbox - Floating variable height footer with scrollable content

Tags: css, flexbox, footer

I'm trying to make a fixed "floating" footer with variable height, that always appears at the bottom even when the content changes.

I have the following [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="app">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="footer"><div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the following CSS: (According to second answer on [Fixed header, footer with scrollable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069734/fixed-header-footer-with-scrollable-content))

```
html, body, #root {
  height: 100%
}

.app {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

However, as the content dynamically changes the page gets distorted and elements overlap each other. I've found that setting `#root` with `height: 275%` makes the page display properly in the expanded state (and only then).

Setting `#root` with `min-height: 100%` makes the footer appear at the middle of the page when there isn't enough content, and it is not floating anymore when the content is scrollable.

Comment: Check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674837/flush-footer-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-bootstrap-4 It is in bootstrap-4, but you can use custom css with the same css properties.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmMrOg

```
<div id="root">
  <div class="app">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div>content</div>

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      footer
      <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
html, body, #root {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.app {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: red;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background:green;
}
```