# Make two columns separately scrollable and the height of the remaining length of the viewport

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, responsive

I've got a JS Fiddle working of exactly what I would like: http://jsfiddle.net/j7ay4qd8/5/

It comprises of two columns which are separately scrollable and different sections of the left column can be easily scrolled to via javascript without affecting the right column or the rest of the page.

However the only way i've got this working for this example is to hardcode the height using the px's of the two nav's.

`height:calc(100vh - 90px);`

Of course this may not work on different browsers, devices and resolutions.

And it will break if any elements are added or the size of those navs changes.

What I really want is for the #form to automatically resize to fill whatever is left of the viewport.

With my current example, if I added another element such as an alert the #content and #sidebar would be longer than the viewport and i'd get jumpy scroll as the whole page scrolls after the #content div has scrolled.

Example with alert and jumpy scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/c4k9u0mr/

I've found this jsfiddle which seems to explain what I want using flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/7yLFL/

However my attempts at doing this with flexbox haven't worked either. The only way that I can get the #content and #guidelines to be separately scrollable is if I give them a fixed height and i'm back to square one of how to make those divs 100% of the container div.

Here's my failed attempt using flexbox (it has a fixed height of 100px in this example): http://jsfiddle.net/jh6d5ztq/

Is it possible to get the first and second JS Fiddle's working without defining a fixed height using px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. All the parents of the elements that takes the remaining height of the viewport need to have a `100%` heights. In bootstrap, use `h-100`.
2. The closest parent of these elements needs to be `flex` and must have `flex-direction: column`. In bootstrap, use `d-flex` and `flex-column`. Some `classes` such as `row` is already `flex` so do not use `d-flex`.
3. Use `flex-grow-1` for the element that takes the remaining height. Again, some `classes` such as `col` have `flex-grow:1`.

#### Bootstrap flex classes

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <div class="py-3 bg-danger">

  </div>
  <div class="py-3 bg-danger">

  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 bg-primary">

  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Bootstrap grid

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="fluid-container h-100">
  <div class="row flex-column h-100">
    <div class="col-auto py-3 bg-danger">

    </div>
    <div class="col-auto py-3 bg-success">

    </div>
    <div class="col bg-primary">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Now, `div.col` / `div.flex-grow-1` takes the remaining height of the viewport. However, if their contents' height is more than that of the `viewport`, they won't do: their height is the same as the height of their content. If you want to make it scrollable, use `overflow: auto`. I guess, bootstrap-4, does not have a class for none of the `overflow` properties. So you should use custom css.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwWpgQ

---

As a side note, if you want to have the [footer at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674837/flush-footer-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-bootstrap-4/50678696#50678696), use these methods but interchange the `col` with `col-auto`

---

If you want to have more than one element scrollable separately, use `overflow-auto` and `h-100` for those elements.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.overflow-auto {
  overflow: auto;
}

.h-200vh {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="fluid-container h-100">
  <div class="row flex-column h-100">
    <div class="col-auto py-3 bg-danger">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto py-3 bg-success">
    </div>
    <div class="col bg-dark d-flex">
      <div class="w-50 h-100 overflow-auto">
        <div class="bg-danger h-200vh"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-50 overflow-auto h-100">
        <div class="bg-primary h-200vh"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzpQRO

---

#### Conclusion:

Use bootstrap grid as you would normally do but use  `flex-column` on `row` and `col` for the element that takes all the remaining height of the viewport. If you want to make it scrollable, use a custom css to apply `overflow:auto`.

---

Comment if you have any question, and I will answer. I have solved your problems, but I wont post it because I think it is best that you try first.

## Update

This is my solution.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jwrzwm

Comment: i'm just playing with this again now trying to figure it out. I've noticed your third example has a weird issue where you can scroll right because there's an offset that's off the page, I think it needs "no-gutters" on the first .row. I'll update when i've got somewhere more concrete

Comment: I got it working using position absolute on the #main to offset from the sidebar and navbar. Although i'm not sure that's necessarily the best method: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPvVdE i'd be interested in seeing your solution that you haven't posted to compare.

Comment: Okay I think i've resolved that just using padding instead of margin (I guess I need to read up on box sizing again) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGwYaP as said i'd still be interested in seeing the solution you didn't post.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jwrzwm You should not change the position of the elements. If you do so, the elements are removed from the normal flow of the content. And then you need to use margin and padding to position the adjacent elements in the right place. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jwrzwm I wrote this one just now. I do not have access to the solution that I wrote that other day. I will go through it. If it was better than this, I will post it next week - after holidays. @JohnMellor

Comment: Is there a reason to use flex for the outer layout (navbar and sidebar) when you could use the grid or fixed positioning?

Comment: @JohnMellor You use less fixed css properties and the element does not overlap each other. In you solution, though you have set `margin-left` of  navbar, but it overlaps the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks it did help, although saying you solved the problem and then saying you wouldn't post said solution was frustrating and not what I think this community should be about.