# Stop Bootstrap 4 footer from rising up

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My bootstrap 4 footer rises up on pages where the body has less content.

Below is an image of the problem.

[footerproblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8SRz.png)

```css
footer {
  background-color: white;
  color: #d5d5d5;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
footer a {
  color: #d5d5d5;
}
hr.light-100 {
  border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="marker">blah blah blah.
        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-instagram">
         <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="marker">more blah blah.
        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook">
         <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
        </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <hr class="light-100">
        <h5>&copy; app.com</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If there is anything else I have forgot to attach please let me know and I will edit the post.

I have played around with `footer: sticky; / fixed;` but that does not solve the problem.

The footer is also too tall but whenever I have added in a `height` css variable, the height is reduced however the text stays in place.

[funkyheight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9oQC.png)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can you please add a snippet or jsfiddle link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flush footer to the bottom of the page in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674837/flush-footer-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: @mahan I have seen your answer on that question and have tried implementing `main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
}` however the problem still exists.

Comment: @Trillz could you post all of  your html code or a similar code?

Comment: @Daut Thanks, this seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: @Trillz I will add it as an answer then :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use css grid.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>main</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

in `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;` `auto` maps to `header` and `footer`, and `1fr` maps to your `main` content.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to fix this problem is to layout your page as follows:

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

with the following CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
header, footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This works with or without Bootstrap, but if you're not using Bootstrap you probably also want

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

(which is already included in Bootstrap).

Here's an example, using Bootstrap v4:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
header, footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
footer {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<main role="main">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a. Metus dictum at tempor commodo. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Tempus egestas sed sed risus. Pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut. Viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare. In pellentesque massa placerat duis. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis.

<p>Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc. Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel. In fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed libero. Vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio. Sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget magna. Pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet. Sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus a.

<p>Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl. Velit scelerisque in dictum non. Integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Magna eget est lorem ipsum. Vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Mollis nunc sed id semper risus in. Id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Netus et malesuada fames ac.
</div>
<div class="col">
<p>Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis. Integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo. Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt. Sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in. Et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non. Velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. In hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum. Euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a.

<p>Non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget velit. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit.
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">I'm your footer. Always at the bottom of the screen. When the page content is too tall, I get pushed down. I also adjust my height according to my contents.</span>
  </div>
</footer>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I am indeed using the layout above, I am using the Django framework. When I add your CSS, the navbar reduces in height by about half and the footer still has the same problem.

Comment: @Trillz, sounds like not all of the above CSS is applying as you probably have stronger selectors in your CSS. Without a *runnable* [mcve] displaying the problem I can't help you more.

Comment: I added an example to the answer. Note you don't necessarily need to use `<body>` as container (it can be a child of `<body>`, if your content requires it) but, in most cases, there is no reason not to use `<body>` for it.

Comment: Yea one of the problems was that the CSS was taking hours to update so any changes I was making weren't being reflected immediately. I really appreciate the example you have put in, I will refer back to that in the future. I am still new so will try to demonstrate a MCV example in future. Best regards.