# Keeping view-port height even with less content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]I require to keep the content area always min, view-port height on even less content. as well it can be grow and footer can be pull down on more content added. how to get this from bootstrap layout approach?

here is my try :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <header id="page-hero" class="site-header">
    <nav class="site-nav navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-secondary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#iboToggleNavi"
                aria-controls="#iboToggleNavi" aria-label="ibo Toggle Navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#page-hero" class="navbar-brand">IBO</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="content vh-100" style="background: green">
    //but height is more than the view port even less content!?
  </div>
  <footer class="container-fluid">
    <p> &nbsp; &copy; Company 2017-2018</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Apart from your question: youre missing a `</div>` right above `</nav>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flush footer to the bottom of the page in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674837/flush-footer-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: If the answer above solves  your problem, up-vote it so that it because more visible.