# Remove space in panel-footer during mobile

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms

Im trying to remove the empty space showing below the footer when the page is on mobile mode. I want it to automatically stretch to fill the width. Some of the codes are for script but I included it. I also remove the script because its all logic and does not affect the design.

Below is the code that I am using.

In my css to fill spaces on top and sides.

```css
<style>
    .button {
        background-color: deepskyblue;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 10px 25px 0px;
    }

    .button1 {
        background-color: deepskyblue;
        color: white;
        border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
    }

        .button1:hover {
            background-color: deepskyblue;
            color: white;
        }

    h1 {
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 26.4px;
    }

    h3 {
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 15.4px;
    }

    p {
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    blockquote {
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 21px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    pre {
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 18.5667px;
    }

    panel-footer {
        background-color: none;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .mob-horizontal {
            padding: 0 !important
        }

        .mob-vertical {
            margin: 0 !important
        }

        .mob-row {
            min-height: 0 !important
        }

            .mob-row div.col-md-4 {
                min-height: 0 !important
            }

        .panel-group {
            margin-bottom: 0 !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<div class="container mob-horizontal" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 mob-horizontal mob-vertical" style="margin-top: 5em;">
            <div class="panel-group text-sm-center">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right: 15px;">
                                        <select id="translate" class="navbar-text form-control" style="width: 80px; color: #1281bb; font-size: 13px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); background-image: none; border: 1px solid rgb(56, 162, 94); box-shadow: none">
                                            <option value="0">List 1</option>
                                            <option value="1">List 2</option>
                                            <option value="2">List 3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body mob-horizontal">
                        <div class="row" style="margin: 0 !important">
                            <br />
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div id="message" style="color: red;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="questionnaire-container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <p id="description" style="padding: 10px">Can you solve this?</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <button type="button" class="button button1" onclick="onNextButton('yes')" style="width: 150px; max-width: 100%;">
                                            Yes
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button" class="button button1" onclick="onNextButton('no')" style="width: 150px; max-width: 100%;">
                                            No
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div id="iframe-container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <h3 id="iframe-title" style="padding: 25px"></h3>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <hr />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div id="iframe-placeholder"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="contact-container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <h1 id="tellTitle" style="padding: 25px"></h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <p id="telldesc1" style="padding: 20px"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <p id="telldesc2" style="padding: 25px"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <center>
                                        <a id="reset" onclick="onResetButton()"></a>
                                    </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <center>
                                            <div id="Panel1">
                                                <p style="padding:35px">Looking for? <a id="clickhere" onclick="onClickHereButton()" style="font-weight:bolder; color:black"></a></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </center>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server">Sample Link</asp:HyperLink>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="true" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Below is the image to help.

[image]

Comment: Can you post full code please

Comment: @Awais I added a photo I hope it can help.

Comment: Yeah but i cant inspect photo as above codes looks fine

Comment: @Awais I updated the code. Its seems to me that the panel is the problem

Comment: it seems ok to me as i have tested that https://www.screencast.com/t/zklcG6yhDA6J

Comment: maybe its on the masterpage ill check that one

Answer (score 0):

you can use position absolute and relative  :
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

another way is use flex box
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I tried using position but it does not fix the problem. I will try flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Use these classes for the main `container`.

- `d-flex`: to make it flex
- `flex-column`: to change its direction to `column`.
- `h-100`: to give it a 100% height.

Use these classes for the main `row`.

- `flex-grow-1` & `flex-sm-grow-0`: to let it occupy all the available space on mobile only. Doing so, the footer is pushed at the very bottom of the page. If you want to have sticky footer on all the screen, irrespective of their viewport size, use ònly `flex-grow-1`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 flex-sm-grow-0 ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 mob-horizontal mob-vertical" style="margin-top: 5em;">
      <div class="panel-group text-sm-center">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading text-center">/*content here*/</div>
          <div class="panel-body mob-horizontal">/*content here*/</div>
          <div class="panel-footer text-center">/*content here*/</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer bg-danger">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

---

Both `html` and `body` must have 100% height. So use `h-100`.

---

Their are a couple of ways to have sticky footer, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674837/flush-footer-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-bootstrap-4/50678696#50678696) may be helpful too.

Bootstrap has allso a similar footer. Visit [getbootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/)

Comment: I added a photo. To show the problem. Ill try to use what you have suggested.