# Bootstrap 4 full screen page with fix footer and nav: content doesn't fill and overflow

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a template page with a navbar and a footer where I might add later column inside the main div (container-fluid) but I get stuck with two issues.
The footer is a div that I use as a logging space. It stays fixed at the bottom and I fill it with logs every time I do an action on the page. The content might grow bigger than the space available and scrollbar appears. The navbar is a standard navbar.
The problem appears when I try to fill the container with random data or a textarea. The main div (and the body)  are bigger than the main view and overflow the footer.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yekL96nc/)

Note that the two parts are colored just to see the issues. The lightcyan part should fill the screen above the footer or at least not grow once it hits it (you can test it by growing the textarea).

My first idea was to set html and body to 100% height, ignore navbar (not sure about its height) leave footer with its fixed height (needed this way to allow using it as a logger) and calculate the main div height. It doesn't work. Note that part of the code comes from examples taken from bootstrap's website.

```
<body>
 <header>
  <nav></nav>
 </header>
 <div class="container-fluid">textarea and columns here</div>
 <footer>
  <div class="content">connecting..</div>
 </footer>  
</body>
```

Comment: Position:fixed on the footer - Does that help ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping i'm trying to use Mahan's answer but it stil has an issue with growing footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap all the content of the body in a container that is flex, and its flex-direction is column.
2. All the parents of main container need to have 100% height.
3. Use `.flex-grow-1` on the main container so that it takes all the available space.
4. Hide overflow of the main container
5. Scroll overflow of the immidiate child of the main container. It must be the parent of all of the main content.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <header class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 p-5 bg-primary">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="container-fluid flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="row h-100 overflow-auto">
      <div class="col bg-danger">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis totam corporis alias qui repellendus optio consectetur nihil suscipit ipsa dolorem in ab, illo, hic placeat iste necessitatibus eum accusamus magni! Perspiciatis, itaque dolore, veritatis
        et sequi obcaecati ipsum fuga deserunt laborum assumenda ducimus facilis pariatur explicabo? Ex veritatis placeat minus enim iure ea deserunt ut optio. Est odio a omnis! Veritatis laborum sit, ea laboriosam nihil laudantium numquam ab modi ipsam
        doloribus obcaecati consectetur nam magnam non sequi illum vero facilis voluptatibus quibusdam unde sunt sapiente! Pariatur adipisci nostrum deserunt! Dolorem assumenda inventore nisi eligendi officia rerum nostrum ea voluptates esse atque deserunt
        culpa ex nobis quod est, fugit molestias recusandae sint iusto ut rem cum itaque dolor magnam. Eligendi! Hic porro incidunt iure culpa necessitatibus repellendus inventore laboriosam expedita neque consectetur. Reprehenderit assumenda minima eum
        laboriosam impedit, omnis esse molestias vero ut? Totam corrupti dolore excepturi fugit dolorum aliquid. Provident blanditiis quasi expedita excepturi ipsa dicta odit, aspernatur ad quisquam illo? Dolores perspiciatis magnam nulla odio rerum tenetur
        inventore fuga. Quo sed eius sapiente, et eligendi blanditiis repellendus saepe! Commodi ipsa explicabo tempore. Dolor voluptas consequuntur amet vero harum nesciunt veritatis placeat? Dolorem ducimus a temporibus perspiciatis cum ipsum tempora
        recusandae unde, repudiandae, nostrum esse magnam velit, consequatur debitis! Quos, ad quaerat optio cumque dolorum facere excepturi eligendi quod rerum suscipit adipisci sapiente animi? Consectetur excepturi tempora nemo libero facere pariatur
        assumenda quisquam porro. In sint voluptas at maxime. Facilis eveniet voluptatem voluptas, libero saepe autem nulla sequi ducimus id quisquam quos aperiam reiciendis ipsa! Nesciunt quae, delectus laboriosam dicta nostrum dolorem inventore rerum
        tempore assumenda animi numquam architecto. Ab ullam amet dolorum impedit debitis id tenetur, nesciunt, exercitationem ut natus a consequuntur harum. Modi illum assumenda earum deserunt voluptatum, non minima hic ad voluptate ullam quae maxime
        expedita? Numquam rem blanditiis, ducimus commodi assumenda corrupti odit mollitia iure inventore molestiae velit quod. Itaque architecto dolores optio voluptatum porro saepe maxime, magnam, perspiciatis amet repellendus fuga eum earum voluptas?
        Quasi sunt, hic consequatur non dolor dolorem, impedit perferendis autem minus labore ea maiores distinctio laudantium eaque quis optio illum voluptatem repudiandae blanditiis magni, repellat et accusamus amet! Aliquid, amet. Deserunt voluptatem
        at excepturi odit maiores quas aut enim consequuntur obcaecati architecto. Fuga nulla maiores vel maxime? Totam a adipisci libero qui, dolore velit rerum optio animi voluptate facilis? Quisquam? Aperiam, quis est pariatur accusantium nulla sed
        minima vel quae facilis, fugiat non qui amet velit quas beatae cupiditate eius sit possimus repellat. Mollitia incidunt magnam et enim, aut doloribus. Dignissimos, a non. Praesentium cupiditate corporis quis harum reprehenderit doloremque fugit
        natus, laudantium rem, facere explicabo aut neque modi? Omnis id minima alias explicabo recusandae ut. Dolorem repellat exercitationem laudantium! Doloremque ea molestias, ratione iure fuga distinctio beatae sit eveniet similique animi excepturi
        non error provident rem amet ullam tempora cum recusandae, eum velit harum? Aut quos hic corporis et. Illum quia dolore, numquam reprehenderit consequuntur officia incidunt ea voluptatum quae, ipsum labore a omnis hic sed necessitatibus impedit.
        Aspernatur quo nam expedita tenetur quibusdam rerum iste ab odio illo. Autem facere fuga aliquam asperiores eius saepe, qui aut amet ratione harum alias tenetur quia, earum expedita voluptate dolor, cumque porro ex nobis eveniet distinctio blanditiis?
        A voluptate eius delectus? Quasi, illum ut quibusdam vitae molestias atque a, modi adipisci similique distinctio cum at animi, aut pariatur consequuntur ad enim dolore? Sit aliquam dignissimos sunt ducimus nihil itaque non reprehenderit? Iure
        error deleniti distinctio esse nam vel nulla aliquid porro consequuntur eius architecto rerum soluta quod ex dolorem at ducimus, quam odio sapiente! Unde dignissimos ratione quas dicta dolorum qui! Error dignissimos eius cupiditate, ipsam labore
        illo. Eos repudiandae, beatae assumenda laboriosam minima veniam dolorum consequatur pariatur neque quidem inventore animi rerum nemo ipsa ut aliquid fuga eaque? Blanditiis, aliquid. Modi placeat nemo quos soluta suscipit? Rem necessitatibus dolorem
        maiores culpa ducimus accusamus cumque sequi qui unde iste aspernatur labore officiis nisi debitis itaque blanditiis tempora, eveniet consectetur! Nesciunt, quam! Obcaecati, quis odit sint beatae reiciendis suscipit labore et eaque pariatur velit,
        ut inventore! Fuga, repudiandae iste, voluptatem corrupti quibusdam error illum quas fugiat asperiores ea omnis ratione qui soluta! Dignissimos ab voluptate accusantium autem facilis architecto, illo sapiente mollitia minima praesentium recusandae
        enim officia officiis unde tempore neque repudiandae perferendis tenetur suscipit eos commodi quis dolorum! Explicabo, odio beatae? Doloribus dolore asperiores eveniet, facere corporis magni aliquid, ratione ipsa minima consequuntur, quos nam
        enim officiis repudiandae voluptatem. Animi assumenda, deserunt placeat labore iusto eos quisquam officiis architecto nobis explicabo. Repudiandae minima facere laboriosam itaque inventore unde non optio praesentium eligendi voluptates culpa et
        corrupti aperiam tenetur incidunt reprehenderit dolorem sit quisquam, sed asperiores veritatis nam vel ipsum dicta! Non. Provident saepe ullam minus laboriosam sit nam rerum! In quidem minima reiciendis, non amet vero sed unde deleniti veritatis
        mollitia voluptatem. Excepturi maiores error consequatur dolore labore reiciendis libero quisquam? Accusantium earum suscipit atque architecto dolorum itaque aliquid error asperiores neque ad rem perferendis expedita a voluptate, similique id
        vero? Quidem iusto expedita ab, consectetur magni similique suscipit aperiam non. Veritatis debitis rem hic, at in deleniti dolorem architecto velit illo repudiandae, eligendi a. Obcaecati ducimus voluptate placeat nulla facere odio, id aut illo
        numquam nobis expedita dolor non ab. Perferendis beatae placeat soluta, repellat dignissimos id qui impedit explicabo? Magni, fugit? Vel, reprehenderit eius dolorem quasi consequuntur vero dolorum molestias ipsum illo enim, quod neque est vitae
        ratione laboriosam?
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col bg-info p-5"></div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

---

This is similar to the following solution.

[Flush footer to the bottom of the page in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674837/flush-footer-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-bootstrap-4/50678696#50678696)

---

#### Update

As of now both the header and footer has fluid height. Use `height: [x]px;` should you need to have a fixed height footer.

Comment: Nice, but if you put a textarea in the main div and try to make it bigger, the footer shrinks a bit. Also the footer is not fixed. if I put a lot of text in it, it will take a lot of space (I tried to set overflow-auto with no success)

Comment: If I set a footer size it works footer { min-height:100px; max-height: 100px; }

Comment: The footer should not shirnk unless the viewport height is less than or equal to the height of header + footer.

Comment: The footer does not have fixed size. Its size is equal to that of its content. Use height: 100px; instead of min-height and max-heigh should you want to have a 100px tall footer. @maugch

Comment: it still shrinks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448987/footer-shrinks-even-if-size-is-fixed-strange-behaviour