# Footer shrinks even if size is fixed + strange behaviour

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am building a page with fixed Navigation bar and Footer (for log information). Both the content and the Footer can scroll if needed. Thanks to some thinkering and all who answered my previous question I managed to create the code at the end of the question (with Bootstrap 4 and jQuery).

The problem I see is that the footer still shrinks if I resize the textarea by hand. I'd expect to see a scrollbar appear on the main content, but not the footer to shrink.

I've also added a couple of lines on the main content and noticed that it overflows (the text goes out the beige part. If I resize the textarea it goes back inside (that is, the text has the beige background again).

What am I doing wrong?

JFiddle here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mo49q3ry/)

See previous question here:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408645/bootstrap-4-full-screen-page-with-fix-footer-and-nav-content-doesnt-fill-and-o/63408995?noredirect=1#comment112135590_63408995)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}

footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 100px; 
}

textarea {
  height: calc(100% - 147px);
}

</style>
    
</head>

<body>


    <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <header class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 p-0 bg-primary">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
        
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Tools
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-template" href="/">Editor</a>

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>

        <main class="container-fluid flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
          <div class="row h-100 overflow-auto">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row h-100">
                <div class="col-10 d-flex flex-column" style="background-color: bisque;">
                  <div class="row">
                    Execute external commands:<br />
                    <button id="testbtn" class="btn btn-primary">TEST</button>
                    <button id="btnclear" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Console</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row flex-grow-1" style="background-color: beige;">
                    <textarea class="w-100">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis totam corporis alias qui repellendus optio consectetur nihil suscipit ipsa dolorem in ab, illo, hic placeat iste necessitatibus eum accusamus magni! Perspiciatis, itaque dolore, veritatis
                      et sequi obcaecati ipsum fuga deserunt laborum assumenda ducimus facilis pariatur explicabo? Ex veritatis placeat minus enim iure ea deserunt ut optio. Est odio a omnis! Veritatis laborum sit, ea laboriosam nihil laudantium numquam ab modi ipsam
                      doloribus obcaecati consectetur nam magnam non sequi illum vero facilis voluptatibus quibusdam unde sunt sapiente! Pariatur adipisci nostrum deserunt! Dolorem assumenda inventore nisi eligendi officia rerum nostrum ea voluptates esse atque deserunt
                      culpa ex nobis quod est, fugit molestias recusandae sint iusto ut rem cum itaque dolor magnam. Eligendi! Hic porro incidunt iure culpa necessitatibus repellendus inventore laboriosam expedita neque consectetur. Reprehenderit assumenda minima eum
                      laboriosam impedit, omnis esse molestias vero ut? Totam corrupti dolore excepturi fugit dolorum aliquid. Provident blanditiis quasi expedita excepturi ipsa dicta odit, aspernatur ad quisquam illo? Dolores perspiciatis magnam nulla odio rerum tenetur
                      inventore fuga. Quo sed eius sapiente, et eligendi blanditiis repellendus saepe! Commodi ipsa explicabo tempore. Dolor voluptas consequuntur amet vero harum nesciunt veritatis placeat? Dolorem ducimus a temporibus perspiciatis cum ipsum tempora
                      recusandae unde, repudiandae, nostrum esse magnam velit, consequatur debitis! Quos, ad quaerat optio cumque dolorum facere excepturi eligendi quod rerum suscipit adipisci sapiente animi? Consectetur excepturi tempora nemo libero facere pariatur
                      assumenda quisquam porro. In sint voluptas at maxime. Facilis eveniet voluptatem voluptas, libero saepe autem nulla sequi ducimus id quisquam quos aperiam reiciendis ipsa! Nesciunt quae, delectus laboriosam dicta nostrum dolorem inventore rerum
                      tempore assumenda animi numquam architecto. Ab ullam amet dolorum impedit debitis id tenetur, nesciunt, exercitationem ut natus a consequuntur harum. Modi illum assumenda earum deserunt voluptatum, non minima hic ad voluptate ullam quae maxime
                      expedita? Numquam rem blanditiis, ducimus commodi assumenda corrupti odit mollitia iure inventore molestiae velit quod. Itaque architecto dolores optio voluptatum porro saepe maxime, magnam, perspiciatis amet repellendus fuga eum earum voluptas?
                      Quasi sunt, hic consequatur non dolor dolorem, impedit perferendis autem minus labore ea maiores distinctio laudantium eaque quis optio illum voluptatem repudiandae blanditiis magni, repellat et accusamus amet! Aliquid, amet. Deserunt voluptatem
                      at excepturi odit maiores quas aut enim consequuntur obcaecati architecto. Fuga nulla maiores vel maxime? Totam a adipisci libero qui, dolore velit rerum optio animi voluptate facilis? Quisquam? Aperiam, quis est pariatur accusantium nulla sed
                      minima vel quae facilis, fugiat non qui amet velit quas beatae cupiditate eius sit possimus repellat. Mollitia incidunt magnam et enim, aut doloribus. Dignissimos, a non. Praesentium cupiditate corporis quis harum reprehenderit doloremque fugit
                      natus, laudantium rem, facere explicabo aut neque modi? Omnis id minima alias explicabo recusandae ut. Dolorem repellat exercitationem laudantium! Doloremque ea molestias, ratione iure fuga distinctio beatae sit eveniet similique animi excepturi
                      non error provident rem amet ullam tempora cum recusandae, eum velit harum? Aut quos hic corporis et. Illum quia dolore, numquam reprehenderit consequuntur officia incidunt ea voluptatum quae, ipsum labore a omnis hic sed necessitatibus impedit.
                      Aspernatur quo nam expedita tenetur quibusdam rerum iste ab odio illo. Autem facere fuga aliquam asperiores eius saepe, qui aut amet ratione harum alias tenetur quia, earum expedita voluptate dolor, cumque porro ex nobis eveniet distinctio blanditiis?
                      A voluptate eius delectus? Quasi, illum ut quibusdam vitae molestias atque a, modi adipisci similique distinctio cum at animi, aut pariatur consequuntur ad enim dolore? Sit aliquam dignissimos sunt ducimus nihil itaque non reprehenderit? Iure
                      error deleniti distinctio esse nam vel nulla aliquid porro consequuntur eius architecto rerum soluta quod ex dolorem at ducimus, quam odio sapiente! Unde dignissimos ratione quas dicta dolorum qui! Error dignissimos eius cupiditate, ipsam labore
                      illo. Eos repudiandae, beatae assumenda laboriosam minima veniam dolorum consequatur pariatur neque quidem inventore animi rerum nemo ipsa ut aliquid fuga eaque? Blanditiis, aliquid. Modi placeat nemo quos soluta suscipit? Rem necessitatibus dolorem
                      maiores culpa ducimus accusamus cumque sequi qui unde iste aspernatur labore officiis nisi debitis itaque blanditiis tempora, eveniet consectetur! Nesciunt, quam! Obcaecati, quis odit sint beatae reiciendis suscipit labore et eaque pariatur velit,
                      ut inventore! Fuga, repudiandae iste, voluptatem corrupti quibusdam error illum quas fugiat asperiores ea omnis ratione qui soluta! Dignissimos ab voluptate accusantium autem facilis architecto, illo sapiente mollitia minima praesentium recusandae
                      enim officia officiis unde tempore neque repudiandae perferendis tenetur suscipit eos commodi quis dolorum! Explicabo, odio beatae? Doloribus dolore asperiores eveniet, facere corporis magni aliquid, ratione ipsa minima consequuntur, quos nam
                      enim officiis repudiandae voluptatem. Animi assumenda, deserunt placeat labore iusto eos quisquam officiis architecto nobis explicabo. Repudiandae minima facere laboriosam itaque inventore unde non optio praesentium eligendi voluptates culpa et
                      corrupti aperiam tenetur incidunt reprehenderit dolorem sit quisquam, sed asperiores veritatis nam vel ipsum dicta! Non. Provident saepe ullam minus laboriosam sit nam rerum! In quidem minima reiciendis, non amet vero sed unde deleniti veritatis
                      mollitia voluptatem. Excepturi maiores error consequatur dolore labore reiciendis libero quisquam? Accusantium earum suscipit atque architecto dolorum itaque aliquid error asperiores neque ad rem perferendis expedita a voluptate, similique id
                      vero? Quidem iusto expedita ab, consectetur magni similique suscipit aperiam non. Veritatis debitis rem hic, at in deleniti dolorem architecto velit illo repudiandae, eligendi a. Obcaecati ducimus voluptate placeat nulla facere odio, id aut illo
                      numquam nobis expedita dolor non ab. Perferendis beatae placeat soluta, repellat dignissimos id qui impedit explicabo? Magni, fugit? Vel, reprehenderit eius dolorem quasi consequuntur vero dolorum molestias ipsum illo enim, quod neque est vitae
                      ratione laboriosam?</textarea>
                      ab<br />ab<br />ab<br />ab<br />ab<br />ab<br />ab<br />ab<br />ab<br />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <div class="row">
                    <li>
                      <ul>aa</ul>>
                      <ul>aa</ul>>
                    </li>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="container-fluid overflow-auto">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="data" class="col p-1">test<br/>to<br/> fill<br/> the<br/> console<br/> log<br/></div>
          </div>
        </footer>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.4.0/bootbox.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-8vfyGnaOX2EeMypNMptU+MwwK206Jk1I/tMQV4NkhOz+W8glENoMhGyU6n/6VgQUhQcJH8NqQgHhMtZjJJBv3A=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you resize one flex element, the others also resizes. To prevent resizing the footer add the classes "flex-shrink-0" and "flex-grow-0" and set the flex-basis of the footer to 100px.

```
<footer class="container-fluid overflow-auto flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0">
```

```
footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 100px; 
  flex-basis: 100px;
}
```

to make the overflowing part beige you can replace

```
<div class="col-10 d-flex flex-column" style="background-color: bisque;">
```

and

```
<div class="row flex-grow-1" style="background-color: beige;">
```

with

```
<div class="col-10 d-flex flex-column" style="background-color: bisque; position: absolute;">
```

and

```
<div class="row flex-grow-1" style="background-color: beige; position: relative;">
```

Comment: It works indeed. Thanks. I'm still puzzled for the overflowing part (the white ab ab )

Answer (score 1):

```
footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 4rem;
  max-height: 4rem;
}
```

it will work fine :)

Comment: i tried this on the fiddle and it worked there by the way.